# Amazon product search API broke with a signature problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon web services to get the product Price.

It was working fine but after the Amazon made the changes in the API in which associateTag becomes mandatory Parameter,it started giving an Error. So i put an associated tag in the request as:

```
tempQueryString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET\necs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ3A3LA5NYXWPSTGQ&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B003VKR0J0&MerchantId=Amazon&AssociateTag=babyformu-20&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&Service=AWSECommerceService&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=%@T%@%@%@Z&Version=2010-01-01",str2,hour,mint,s];
```

Now it is Giving this error:
`"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."`

I did not make any changes in the signing method.
Here it is:

```
NSString *key = @"9at/FN4mouFxnIV2SsoQTR4iO6x6AWVt2xFvEwmv"; // private key
    NSLog(@"current:    %@ ",queryString);
    NSString *data = queryString;
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    hash = [HMAC base64Encoding];
    NSLog(@"hash value11 == %@",hash);
    encodedString = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)hash, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

I am using this api to get the product detail:

`query=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ3A3LA5NYXWPSTGQ&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B003VKR0J0&AssociateTag=babyformu-20&MerchantId=Amazon&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=%@T%@:%@:%@Z&Version=2009-03-31&Signature=%@",str2,h,m,s,encodedString];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same issues today as well, now they require the associateTag, which I've put in I'm not bringing back any results... Very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my Amazon code relatively easily. I'm using PHP. I just added another parameter:

```
$parameters["AssociateTag"] = myInfo::MY_AMAZON_ASSOCIATE_ID;
```

Then I call:

```
aws_signed_request("com", $parameters, $this->public_key, $this->private_key)
```

AWS Signed Request was created by Ulrich Mierendorff and modified by Sameer Borate.

Comment: I added the associateTag parameter but now it is giving this error:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

Comment: Sounds like you should try the official AWS support forum. Did you register your developer key using a different domain? I don't remember the specifics but your public and private key are tied to a domain, at least that is how some APIs work.